# How do you compress a local video to a custom size in iOS?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

AVAssetExportSession allows me to compress a video using different presets such as AVAssetExportPreset1280x720 like so

```
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPreset1280x720];
exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void)
 {
     handler(exportSession);
 }];
```

But what if I wanted to compress my local video to a custom size such as 640x360. Is there a way to accomplish this?